# How to add the word Menu to a wordpress 2014 theme when in mobile sized width

Tags: wordpress

My wordpress is running a 2014 theme. I am hoping that I can add the word menu next to the lined menu for people who do not know that the lines are a menu. This menu with lines only shows when the site is sized down to the size of a mobile site. The website is dreamgardens.tlchatt.com . I have scoured the web to figure it out. I managed to get my own header image into the theme. Seems like it would be a simple task. I was able to make the area around the button larger in two different ways by changeing style.css . 
 It looks like the change to the mobile menu occurs based on this Javascript.

```
( function( $ ) {
var body    = $( 'body' ),
    _window = $( window );

// Enable menu toggle for small screens.
( function() {
    var nav = $( '#primary-navigation' ), button, menu;
    if ( ! nav ) {
        return;
    }

    button = nav.find( '.menu-toggle' );
    if ( ! button ) {
        return;
    }
```

I am hoping to make the mobile menu have the text menu to the right of it much like this website http://chattanoogagb.kokofitclub.com/. I do not understand this code well enough to locate where the mobile re sized code is and alter it to include the text Menu.

The above Java Script and PHP refers to this style.css entry

```
.menu-toggle {
cursor: pointer;
font-size: 0;
height: 48px;
margin: 0;
overflow: hidden;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: 0;
text-align: center;
width: 48px;
}

.menu-toggle:before {
color: #fff;
content: "\f419";
margin-top: 16px;
}
```

The \f419 seems to refer to a style sheet genericons.css which has this code.

```
.genericon-menu:before {            content: '\f419'; }
```

I am wondering if there is a simple aditional line of code I can insert somewhere to place the word "Menu" somewhere near the mobile toggled menu button. Some kind of subtext or something would be fine.

Comment: Unfortunatly I'm at work and using my cell to answer this. You need to have a look at `functions.js` inside the `js` folder on how the responsiveness of the menu button is handled. I can't exactly tell you straight out of my head, but you should dequeueu `functions.js`, then copy that file over to your child theme, make the changes to suite your needs and enqueue it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the most elegant way maybe to do this, but you need to change the following lines 1000-1004

```
 .menu-toggle:before {
    color: #fff;
    content: "\f419";
    margin-top: 16px;
}
```

to this

```
.menu-toggle:before {
    color: #fff;
    content: "MENU";
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-top: 16px;
}
```

Remember, this goes in your child themes' `style.css`. Don't edit the twentyfourteen theme directly.

Comment: Thank you so much this ended up really saving me a lot of headache. I am going to learn some more css, html, php and Javascript so this will be less of a headache in the future. I assumed someone with a decent knowledge of this could easily figure it out. I ended up combining the two so the final edit was 
    content: "MENU""\00a0""\00a0""\f419";

Answer (score -1):

Based on your site it is not responsive - so my assumption you have no media queries?  Any way I would use 'Responsive Select Menu' from the plugins library. Set it to 768px and you should be all good. Let me know how you get on :)

Comment: Please have a look at the twentyfourteen theme that is shipped with wordpress. It is fully responsive.  The responsiveness of menu button and how it is displayed is done using jquery inside `functions.js` in the `js` folder

Comment: Thanks for the comment but if you have a look at the link that the OP provided it is not responsive. Www.tlchatt.com <- this is not responsive...

Comment: Yes thank you for responding the site theme is responsive the link is dreamsgardens.tlchatt.com I sent the wrong link ugg.

Comment: Hey also that Responsive Select Menu plugin seemed like it would look nice enough and solve the problem but, for whatever reason it did not work at all.